# (Solr) more like this cause this error RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I want to search my articles using `more_like_this`, my controller code looks is below. Also looked [at this post](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Getting-404-for-MoreLikeThis-handler-td498639.html), and tried `ry /solr/select` with `mlt=on` parameter, it doesn't work as well:

```
            article = Article.find(params[:id])
            @search = Sunspot.more_like_this(article) do
                fields :title
                minimum_term_frequency 1
                adjust_solr_params do |params|
                    params["mlt.match.include"] = true
                    params["mlt"] = 'on' # doesn't work
                    params["mlt"] = true # doesn't work
                end
            end
```

Request handler also set in my `solrconfg.xml`

```
    <requestHandler class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler" name="/mlt">
           <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="mlt.mintf">1</str>
            <str name="mlt.mindf">2</str>
         </lst>
       </requestHandler>
```

Log:

```
RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.39 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /solr/mlt</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/solr/mlt</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.39</h3></body></html>

URI: http://localhost:8888/solr/mlt?wt=ruby
Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}
Request Data: "fq=type%3AArticle&mlt.mintf=1&q=id%3AArticle%5C+2144&mlt.fl=title_textv&start=0&rows=30&mlt.match.include=true"

Backtrace: /home/chuhai/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:284:in `adapt_response'
/home/chuhai/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'
/home/chuhai/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.12/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'
/home/chuhai/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/home/chuhai/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/home/chuhai/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/chuhai/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/home/chuhai/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in `post'
/home/chuhai/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:49:in `execute'
/home/chuhai/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.0/lib/sunspot/search/more_like_this_search.rb:16:in `execute'):
  app/controllers/api/v1/articles_controller.rb:9:in `search'
  lib/cors.rb:7:in `call'
  lib/cors.rb:7:in `call'
```